# How to get left table data using mikro-orm and nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, mikro-orm

Please find below code sample of two table book and author and I want to list all books alongs with author detail,

> Book

```
@Entity()
export class Book{

  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property()
  title!: string;

  @ManyToOne({ entity: () => Author }) // or use options object
  author!: Author;

}
```

> Author:

```
@Entity()
export class Author {

  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property()
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

  @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt: Date = new Date();

  @Property()
  name!: string;

  @Property()
  email!: string;

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  age?: number;

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  identities?: string[];

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  born?: Date;

  @OneToMany({ entity: () => Book, mappedBy: 'author', orphanRemoval: true })
  books = new Collection<Book>(this);

  @Property({ version: true })
  version!: number;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

> Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    private readonly orm: MikroORM,
    private readonly em: EntityManager,
  ) {}

  async findBooks(): Promise<any> {
    const books: Book[] = await this.orm.em.find(Book, {});
    return books;
  }
}
```

Currently I am getting result like:  Ref { id: 4 } but I want to get all author detail along with id.

Please correct in service page if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate all relationships by passing *`populate: true`*

Like:

```
const result = await this.bookRepository.findAll({ populate: true });
```

This will return list of all the books with populated author details.

---

**EDIT:**

If you are using an EntityManager, then you can use it like this:

```
const books: Book[] = await this.orm.em.find(Book, {}, { populate: true });
```

Comment: can you update it on service code block

Comment: Yes, you can refer the answer, I have updated it.